# Laravel - empty request value when input contain javascript

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add a feature to my Laravel application that allow users to save Google / facebook / hotgar  Pixels code (javascript code).

The user have a form with input TAG that he can past is pixel.

Now when i submit the form and trying to handle to corm data in my controller...
that input that contain the javascript data... are empty

when

```
<input type="text" class="conversion-code" name="poptinConversionCode[]" value="<script type='text/javascript'></script>"></input>

<input type="text" class="conversion-code" name="poptinConversionCode[]" value='test test'></input>
```

in the controller

```
[poptinConversionCode] => Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => test test
)
```

Why?

And how i can do send javascript to my controller?

Comment: You cant send html tags from form elements. You can escape them using javascript and then send. Check following resource https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If you watch the var dump in a browser it is normal that the content of a script tag is empty.

Try to look at the page source and see if you find the content you are searching.

In Laravel there is no input transformation by default except for trim and emtpy strings to null in 5.4.